# In-app search of market for a particular mime-type opener

Tags: android, google-play, mime-types

I have an application that allows the user to open files.  If there is no app on the phone that can open the file, an error message is displayed.  Is there a way to do an in-app search of the Play Store or Amazon App Store for an app that will open a file of a particular mime-type?  This way if no app that can open the file is found on the device, one from the store can be suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't expose that search functionality. If you want to do an in-app search by app or package name, you could use [the inofficial api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).